# Eigen Matrix from the vector of indices (row, col) and vector of values?

Tags: c++, matrix, eigen, eigen3

Eigen / C++ newbie here.
I do have massive (sparse) matrix to initialize and fill and I do have the vector of indices (row,col) and vector of values that correspond to those. How do I quickly (efficiently) build a matrix out of the two?
At this time, I prepare the vector of Triplets, and then I use **setFromTriplets**, but making that vector of Triplets in the loop is far too inefficient.

I feel that there has to be a better way than a loop. Please help.

```
void ImagingObjects::InitSparseSigmaPriorTriplets(Eigen::VectorXd& signals_vec)
{

Eigen::MatrixXd values = signals_vec.sum() * ( *this->GetSigmaPValues() );

for (size_t i=0; i < sparse_sigma_prior_triplets_vector.size(); ++i) 
{
    int index_row = (int) (*this->GetSigmaPIndices())(i, 0);
    int index_col = (int) (*this->GetSigmaPIndices())(i, 1);
    sparse_sigma_prior_triplets_vector[i] =  (Eigen::Triplet <double> ){ index_row, index_col, values(i) } ;
}
}
```

So basically I prepare these triplets, every time, for every data sample, by cranking the nested loop.
Then, inside the algorithm solver iterative loop, I have this code:

```
size_t array_it = 0;
for (size_t i=0; i < sigma_prior_retain_bool_array.size(); ++i) 
{
    if( sigma_prior_retain_bool_array[i] )
    {
        triplets_sigma_prior[array_it] = *ImagingObjsPtr->GetSparseSigmaPriorTriplet(i);
        array_it++;             
    }       
}   
        
auto end_it = triplets_sigma_prior.begin() + array_it;
Sigma_prior_sparse.setFromTriplets(triplets_sigma_prior.begin(),end_it );
```

Comment: There are many ways. Do you know how many non-zeros you have per column? Are your indexes ordered? Do you have to fill the matrix only once?

Comment: Ok. 
I am processing several millions of signals.
For each signal sample,
(1)  I have to initialize this matrix (prior estimate) with values (that are weights) multiplied by signal strength
(2)  Put the matrix together, and then in the iterative loop, I determine the indices (row,col) of values I want to keep and retain only those, until no new changes come with each new iteration.

Yes, the indices and values are ordered / synchronized.
Non-zeros per column probably varies, I have not checked.

Comment: I now find that there is Eigen::Map but I don't have any idea if that could be relevant or how to use it :(

Comment: You don't have to copy your triplets into `Eigen::Triplet` it is sufficient if you provide an iterator which provides access to a `value()`, `row()` and `col()` function: http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox-devel/classEigen_1_1SparseMatrix.html#acc35051d698e3973f1de5b9b78dbe345. If your entries are already ordered you can use the internal `insertBack` function: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45312500/6870253

Comment: @chtz thank you. My issue is, I do want to avoid having the nested loop that fills the triplets to begin with.
`tripletList.reserve(estimation_of_entries);
for(...)
{
  // ...
  tripletList.push_back(T(i,j,v_ij));
}`

Comment: I did not fully understand your explanation, but it looks like you might want to write direcly into the matrix instead of saving (row,col) and values first. You should provide a minimal example to make your intentions clear (edit the question, not providing info in comments).

Comment: @mfnx you are correct! This mini-editor is awful. I am going to add a minimal example.

Comment: Now if you could provide a compilable example, that would be great. Your question could even get upvotes :). You should know [ask] and provide a [mre]. Only that way people might take the time to answer your questions.

Comment: My question is not a technical "issue" that one may want to reproduce, my code runs and produces the results that it should. What I am trying to do here is to ask for a different. more efficient way to do it and I believe on my end I am being pretty crystal describing the situation. But fair enough, I will make a small example when I can. It is actually in itself not easy to do because if I just give you a 10x10 next thing you may say, "why don't you like the way you did it?" and I won't be able to give you the 800K x 800K easily.

Comment: "How can I do this more efficiently" is also an "issue" (for which we need to know how you are currently doing "this"). We can abstract from the fact that in the MRE you only provide 10x10 instead of millions of entries.