# memory usage with Eigen setFromTriplets

Tags: c++, memory, sparse-matrix, eigen

I would like to fill a sparse matrix with size 300k * 300k with triplets. There are 100k non-zero members in the triplet. According to [Set sparsity pattern of Eigen::SparseMatrix without memory overhead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45301305/set-sparsity-pattern-of-eigensparsematrix-without-memory-overhead), it needs

```
100000 * 100000 * 24B + 100000 * 100000 * 16B = 240GB + 160GB = 400GB
```

memories. If I am right, are there any ways to reduce the memory usage for this size of sparse matrix?

I tried to fill the sparse matrix using `setFromTriplets` from Eigen but the memory crashes.

Comment: If there are only _"...100k non-zero members..."_ why are you calculating for `100k*100k` non-zero members ?  Yes there is an overhead but it's not a few orders of magnitude.

Comment: Eigen's sparse format (compressed) consists of: 1 Scalar per nonzero entry. 1 Row index per nonzero, 1 offset index per column. In row major matrices, it's a column index and an offset per row. So in your case it would be `100k * sizeof(scalar) + 100k * sizeof(int) + 300k * sizeof(int)`. The triplets themselves obviously need `100k * (sizeof(scalar) + 2 * sizeof(int))` Maybe double that if Eigen needs to sort them